# How to pass class name as generic type <T> based on enum value?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the below function.

```
public static string SerializeObjectToXML<T>(object mainColumn) 
{ 
   return string.empty;
}
```

I am trying to pass `classname` based on enum value as below.

```
var tempstr = ClassName.SerializeObjectToXML<EnumClass.class1 == enumvalue ? ClassA: ClassB>(value);
```

Can I do this?  If not how can I achieve this using inline enum condition?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this:

```
var tempstr = EnumClass.class1 == enumvalue
? ClassName.SerializeObjectToXML<ClassA>(value) 
: ClassName.SerializeObjectToXML<ClassB>(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think you are not using generics to your full advantage.  Just change `object` in your code to `T`.  Something like this:

```
public string SerializeObjectToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var wrt = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xs.Serialize(wrt, obj);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
string objXml = SerializeObjectToXml(a);
```